# The limits of integration for a paraboloid and plane.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the volume, $V$, enclosed by the paraboloid
>   $$z=x^2+y^2$$
>   and the plane $2x+z=3$. Determine the limits for the enclosed volume. Do not attempt to evaluate the integral.

Hello, I’m confused on how to get limits for this integral, I drew it and I think $z$ limits are from the paraboloid equation to $z=3-2x$, but after that I’m stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what they are looking for. The "volume $V$" (I would have written "body $K$" or something) is really given as the volume between the paraboloid and the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two surfaces intersect when $$z=x^2+y^2=3-2x \Rightarrow x^2+2x+y^2 = 3$$
Now $$x^2+2x+y^2 = 3 \Rightarrow \left(x+1\right)^2+y^2=4$$

Therefore in cartesian coordinates:
$$V= \int{\int{\int dz}dy}dx=\int_{x=-3}^{x=1}{\int_{y=-\sqrt{4-(x+1)^2}}^{y=\sqrt{4-(x+1)^2}}{\int_{z=x^2+y^2}^{z=3-2x}1dz}dy}dx$$

In Cylindrical coordinates, starting from:
$$V= \int{\int{\int_{z=x^2+y^2}^{z=3-2x}1dz}}dA=\int{\int{\left[4-\left(x+1\right)^2-y^2\right]}}dA$$
Then using $r=x^2+y^2$, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$:
$$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}{\int_{r=0}^{r=2}{\left[   {4-\left(r\cos\theta+1\right)^2-\left(   {r\sin\theta}  \right)^2}   \right]}}rdrd\theta$$

[image]

Comment: Sexy plot daddy

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we can find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates that we'll have to integrate across by solving for the intersection of the plane and the paraboloid. To do this, we rearrange our equations as $z=3-2x$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ and set them equal to get
$$3-2x=x^2+y^2 \implies 4=(x+1)^2+y^2$$
So our region is a circle of radius $2$ around the point $(x,y)=(-1,0)$. Now we have our limits by rearranging our circle into $x=-1 \pm\sqrt{4-y^2}$. The $z$ values that we will integrate across will simply be from the paraboloid to the plane so we can write
$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-1-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{-1+\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{3-2x} dz \ dx  \ dy$$
or
$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-1-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{-1+\sqrt{4-y^2}}(3-2x) - (x^2+y^2) \ dx \ dy$$